# Possible world ending scenario if nowadays earth population can learn and practice magic

Tags: magic, humans, technological-development, apocalypse

For a long time I had imagine that the most advance human can do if we can learn and practice magic and other mysticism like we learn at schools like hogwarts while also interact and develop technology and science nowadays.

In this scenario, in our world nowadays some group of peoples manages to spread virally a ton of ancient knowledge of magic that can be practised by anyone and it really worked. Like any other things that spread on internet, the government late to contains it and it have already spread troughout the world.

The rules:

1. Magic and mysticism right here ranging from elemental magic mastery, make astral projection of ourselves, necromancy, curses, to manage chakra, anti magic charms, basicly almost anything except time magic (while as a soul we can re-see the past, and catch a glimpse of possible future),and telekinesis are restricted to lifted what we can already lifted by our muscle, tough we can joined together to lifted more heavy items. (but yeah everybody can do the avatar element bending ability, light a stick, and do magic battle like harry potter, with proper trainings).
2. Learn magic will be like learn to drive. While simple task are able to be mastered by anyone (any functional human being can learn to sparks a fire with their fingers) some high magic needs to spent your lifetime to master, like necromancy, and you still can command a horde of zombies since it would need you to learn to control two or more bodies while you still just have one brain (No real ressurection magic, but there's advance healing knowledge).
3. Learn the magic is like learn to alter the 'code program' of the universe with our will. While spells and incantations helps, we do not really need it if we grasp its concept. And it is also affect to develop our perspective on physics. Our science and technology will also get a big leap, since we know our nature and metaphysics better.
4. The knowledge would also include a history of sentient beings before us, and also legendary creatures, tough we will immediately known that they are ceased to exist now. We still don't really know about how the universe created, and wether there's some advance alien life form still exist out there.
5. Telepathy also real, while you still can't easily do mind reading/ mind control since people at normal conditions with little practice can developed a subconscious 'wall defense' on such attacks.
6. Teleportation knowledge is there, but no human could do it.
7. While it is difficult we can learn transmutation, and law of equivalent change still apply. Thus you need more than water to turn it to wine.

The Questions:

1. How do you think we would react on 1-2 decades after this knowledge went to public? How will our society changes and what effect it would have on our norm and technology?
2. While it can solve numerous nowadays problem, it would brought new problems to us. What is the possible scenario in more advance technological and magic civilization in the future (say 50-100 years from now), that all of this will guide our species to our own extinction (no aliens, gods-demigods, or mystical creatures involved)?

Thank you

Comment: Hello, and welcome to WB SE. I'm sorry to say that your question is very, very broad, and is [unanswerable in its current state](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3033/is-worldbuilding-a-what-if-site?rq=1). Quite simply, the changes you're describing have deep, and far reaching consequences. It's impossible to predict exactly what would happen from a societal, cultural, political, and militaristic POV. And even if someone here were to answer, their post would be entirely opinion based, as there's no good way to prove which course of events is more likely.

Comment: Check out the WB SE [Risk Factors](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3206/worldbuilding-scope-risk-factors?cb=1) for more information.

Comment: Changes in society as we think of it would change. Since the existence of magic proves that the laws of nature aren't constant this would throw the scientific world   in to complete disorder. Since since can't explain it religion and philosophy would fill that gap. expect a religious revile world wide, as well as many new religions and philosophies forming based around magic.

Comment: The government would possible outlaw certain form of magic consider dangerous. There were probably pass laws trying to prevent insane or criminal individuals from getting they hand on certain knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Answer for question is terribly related to technicalities.

For example - complicated antiseptic spell would be a game changer in medieval times, while in XXIst century it may be just a curiosity, because it may be inferior in relation to hydrogen peroxide. A guy with fireball may actually make a person armed with machine gun laugh...

Or not...

It all depends on relative strength of specific magic techniques.

There would be for sure (regardless of magic power) an awful ideological shift. All major religions would face their cosmology ruined... The only (minor) consolation for priests would be that proponents of New Atheism would not look much more better...

Changes in to society... All based on minor details... Healing spells? Can influence life expectancy. Divination spells can eliminate practically all crime... or occultation spells and curses can actually allow to commit perfect crime...

Would there be really powerful spell-equivalent of WMD? Accessible to non state actors? Or mentally unbalanced people? Because if yes then our own extinction can be quite fast...